# I backed up my Android device and I want to restore it on my iphone 5!

Tags: iphone, ios, backup, restore, android

Can anybody please help me?!
I want to restore a non apple device back up to my iphone 5 and I can't so please anybody's help would be great! I have a Samsung galaxy S7 edge and I got a iPhone 6s.

Answer (score 4):

### Backing up Contents of Android Phone to Compter

1. On your Android phone, go to your Contacts. Tap the `menu` button and tap `Import/Export`. Tap `Export to Storage`, select the contact data you want to transfer ("Phone") and select `OK`.
2. Connect your Android to your PC (USB) and put your phone in `Disk Drive mode`. Your phone will appear as a drive (or two drives if you have an SD card) in My Computer or on your Mac desktop.
3. Create a new folder on your desktop. Look through the files on your Android device and drag and drop the content you want to transfer to your iPhone (photos, music, and videos).
4. Finally, search for a VCF file on your Android phone and save that file too (**Don't put it in the folder necessarily; just keep it on your desktop**). This is where all your contacts are.
5. Drag and drop that folder to your iPhone data folder. You're now ready to transfer the saved data to your iPhone.

### Photos and Videos to iPhone

1. Connect iPhone to computer and open iTunes. Click on the iPhone on the top right corner (assuming iTunes 11.0 here), then go to the `Photos` tab in the main window. Check `Sync photos` In the drop-down menu, click `Choose Folder` and navigate to the Android data folder on your desktop. Your photos will appear in your iPhone's Photos app.
2. You can do the same for videos; just click `Videos` instead and choose that same folder.

### Music to iPhone

1. Drag the iPhone folder from your desktop over your iPhone's name in the iTunes sidebar. All of your songs will be transferred to your iPhone. (You can also use this trick to transfer any other music from your desktop to your iPhone.) The music can be found in your iPhone's Music app.
2. Alternatively, if the first option didn't work for you, click `File`, `Import Folder`, and select the folder with all of your music from your Android phone. This will import all music into iTunes. After this is done (it may take awhile), go back to your iPhone by selecting it in the top right corner. Click `Music`, `Sync All Music`, then `Sync Now`.

### Contacts to iPhone

1. You need to set up an e-mail account on your iPhone for this one to work. Then, back on your computer, send yourself an e-mail with the VCF file as an attachment. Open that e-mail on your iPhone and tap the attachment. A message will pop up at the top. Tap this button "Add all contacts." Your contacts will be saved to your iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

There are also several apps on the iOS app store to assist in migrating data. Most have a companion app on the Google Play Store to prepare the data and send it directly from one device to the other without needing a computer or cloud service.

- http://www.jamfsoftware.com/products/Relo/

Apple has an app on the Google Play Store that prepared the data and works out of the box with a new iOS phone (or one that is wiped):

- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apple.movetoios
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201196

The nice thing about these apps is they assist in re-downloading any matched free apps and Apple's app for android will add paid apps to your App Store wishlist so they are queued for you to purchase as you wish.